# pass parameter to Task.StartNew without anonymous function

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was just trying to learn threading and I was wondering can we pass parameter and use return values while creating threads .i am creating Thread using **Task.Factory.StartNew** .I am just trying to figure something without anonymous function.

Can somebody help me in better understanding.Should I use delegate here.
Below is the code that i want to work with(just for learning purpose I do not want to use anonymous and lambda) .Is it possible?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{

    private static int printMessage(int c)
    {
        int ctr = c;
        for (ctr = 0; ctr <= 1000000; ctr++)
        { }
        return ctr;

    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(printMessage));

        t.Start();
        t.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + t.Result); 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You don't need to call `t.Start()`, the task is already started. 2) Unless you are using one of the overloads that take in `TaskCreationOptions` or a `TaskSchedueller` you really should use `Task.Run(` and pass in a lambada, it really is the "preferred" way to do it the current version of .NET

Comment: Yes Sir,I removed t.start() (infact it was giving run time error).i will be using lambda but I just wanted to see if is possible to pass parameter .I am having .Net 4.0 in which Task.Run is not available so I tried this.Just for knowledge purpose...Well great Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, sure. You have to use `Func<object, T>` and pass in the value for `c` as an `object`. Since the task has a result, you should use `Task<int>` instead of `Task`:

```
private static int printMessage(object c)
{
    int ctr = (int)c;
    for (ctr = 0; ctr <= 1000000; ctr++)
    { }
    return ctr;

}

public static void Main()
{
    Task<int> t = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Func<object, int>(printMessage), 1);

    t.Start();
    t.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + t.Result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I think,I should learn more about relationship between Func and Action .Also,why we changed to object. why it cant be  Func<int,int> as we are getting int and sending int.I tried,it didnt worked.Any suggestion Sir

Comment: Because it can't, period. You have to use `object` and cast it yourself.